# Рекурсивный обход папок c генерацией пути встреченных файлов

Tags: python, рекурсия

Есть один класс gen_files_path.
Туда передается название искомой папки и путь. Если путь не указан, то корневой диск.

Процесс: обход указанного каталога, если элемент файл, генерировать путь к нему. Если папка, то то внутри неё обойти, генерируя пути файлов, если в ней пака... т.д.
При нахождении искомой папки,  печатать её путь и строку 'найдено' и завершать обход.

Вопрос следующий: не могу понять как дописать туда рекурсивный обход папок.

код:

```
import os
from _collections_abc import Iterable


def gen_files_path(folder: str, path=None) ->Iterable[str]:
    if path is None:
        path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.sep))
    for i_elem in os.listdir(path):
        temp = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(path, i_elem))
        if os.path.isdir(temp) and i_elem != folder:
            continue
        yield temp
        if i_elem == folder:
            return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо continue вызываете себя же (`gen_files_path`), в качестве аргумента `path` использовав `temp` (как я понимаю, абсолютный путь, содержащий ещё и папку, в которой нужно пошариться)

Comment: Можете скинуть в итоге готовый код пожалуйста, а то заинтересовался данной программой!

Answer (score 1):

Подумав, переписал функцию с помощью os.walk()

Решение берёт из кортежа, возвращаемого os.walk() ссылку link, с именем файла file, соединяет в строку и возвращает с помощью yield. При следующем обращении, разделяет ссылку split('\') и проверяет, совпадает ли имя последней папки с искомым. Если совпадает, то прерываем цикл.

```
def gen_files_path(link: str, search: str) -> Iterable[str]:
    for link, dirs, files in list(os.walk(link)):
        for file in files:
            yield links + '\\' + file
            if links.split('\\')[-1] == search:
                return
```

Но потом ещё подумала и написал выражение:

```
gen_files_path = [links + '\\' + file
              for links, dirs, files in list(os.walk(folder))
              for file in files
              ]
```

Дальше просто цикл по результатам и прерывание после нахождения цели