# Можно ли как то получить массив пути всех папок с одинаковым названием, хранящимся на определённом диске? Python 3

Tags: python

Всем привет. На сервере созданы учетные записи пользователей "C:\users...". У этих пользователей есть множество каталогов в которых хранятся папки с одинаковым названием - "c:\user\desktop\main_folder1\folder, c:\user\desktop\main_folder2\folder, c:\user\desktop\main_folder3\folder". Можно ли получить массив с путями этих папок? Грубо говоря скрипт, который просканирует всех пользователей в "C:\users" и выдаст этот массив в переменную?

Comment: Используйте библиотеку os

Comment: посмотрите https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1343844

Comment: Если прямо отвечать на ваш вопрос то Ответ: **можно**.

Answer (score 0):

Если отвечать на ваш вопрос, ответ: да, можно.

­​

­​

­​

­​

­​

­​

­​

­​

­​

---

А если серъёзно, вот как это я бы сделал:

```
import os

map = {}

for root, dirs, _files in os.walk("./"):
  filename = os.path.basename(root)
  if not filename in map:
    map[filename] = []
  map[filename].append(root)

for key, dirs in map.items():
  if len(dirs) <= 1:
    continue
  print(" -= Folder name:", key, "=-")
  for dir in dirs:
    print(dir)
  print("")
  print("")
```

Получится вывод типа такого:

```
 -= Folder name: en-gb =-
./[_DELETED_]\admin\language\en-gb
./[_DELETED_]\catalog\language\en-gb
./[_DELETED_]\install\language\en-gb


 -= Folder name: menu =-
./[_DELETED_]\admin\language\en-gb\extension\menu
./[_DELETED_]\admin\language\uk-ua\extension\menu


 -= Folder name: ru-ru =-
./[_DELETED_]\admin\language\ru-ru
./[_DELETED_]\catalog\language\ru-ru
./[_DELETED_]\install\language\ru-ru


 -= Folder name: howto =-
./[_DELETED_]\admin\language\ru-ru\howto
./[_DELETED_]\admin\language\uk-ua\howto


 -= Folder name: uk-ua =-
./[_DELETED_]\admin\language\uk-ua
./[_DELETED_]\catalog\language\uk-ua
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ, ограничился вот этим.
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("C:\\users"):
  if '\folder' in root:
      mass = root
      path.append(mass)